# Issue with plotting sin wave on Matlab

Tags: matlab, signal-processing, trigonometry, sampling

I have to plot the signal m(t) = A*Sin(2*pi*1000*t) and I am using the following Matlab code to do it.

```
Fm=1000;%1 kHz

Fs = 2*Fm;

t = 0:1/Fs:10; % ( that is, time will run from 0 to 10 with a sample at every 1/2000th second )
Am=1;%amplitude
m=Am*sin(2*pi*Fm*t);

figure(1)
plot(t,m)
title('Message signal')
xlabel('Time in Seconds') 
ylabel('m(t)')
```

However, I am getting the plot as

[image]

But on the other hand, if I use the following code,

```
Fm=1000;%1 kHz

t=linspace(0,10,2000);
Am=1;%amplitude
m=Am*sin(2*pi*Fm*t);

figure(1)
plot(t,m)
title('Message signal')
xlabel('Time in S')
```

[image]

I am getting a proper sin wave. What's actually happening here? What is wrong with the first code?

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the **first code snippet** is that the sampling period is *exactly half* the period of the sinusoid. Due to the specific sampling instants that you use, you always sample the signal *at its nulls*. That's why you get values close to `0` (they are not exactly `0` because of the *numerical inaccuracy* inherent to [floating-point arithmetic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)).

In the **second code snippet**, since [`linspace`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html) is *inclusive* at its end points, the sampling period is slightly different. So you don't have the same problem as above, and you do get a sinusoid. However, you have a different problem which is now made evident, namely [aliasing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aliasing#Sampling_sinusoidal_functions) due to *insufficient sampling*. Observe how the frequency of the plotted sinusoid is very different (much smaller) from what it should be.

The **solution** to both problems is to *increase the sample rate*. According to the [Nyquist criterion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate), a sample rate at least twice the maximum signal frequency would be enough to *reconstruct* the original signal. But that does not mean that *directly plotting* the samples taken at that rate will produce a graph resembling the signal. For that you need a factor *significantly greater* than `2`. Also, *avoid choosing the sample rate as an integer multiple* of the sinusoid frequency, to prevent problems caused by the sampling process being "coupled" to the signal variations as in your first snippet.

So, in your code, try for instance `Fs = 100/3*Fm` (you may need to zoom in to see the signal properly).

Comment: reducing the sampling period to a value smaller than the sinusoid period also means that increasing sampling frequency to a value greater than the sinusoid frequency right? So can I simply use Fs = 3*Fm as sampling frequency?

Comment: @MuhammedRoshan Any `Fs`  above `2*Fm` would do according to the Nyquist criterion. In practice, if you plot the samples directly you need a factor greater than `2` to have the plot resemble the signal. Also, I suggest not to use an interger multiple of `Fm`, to avoid things like in the first graph. So try something like `Fs = 100/3*Fm` for instance (and zoom in to see the signal)

Answer (score 0):

Fm=1000 #%1 kHz

here is the python version

```
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
Fs = 2*Fm

#t = 0:1/Fs:10  #( that is, time will run from 0 to 10 with a sample at every 1/2000th second )
t=np.linspace(0,10,Fs)

Am=1   #%amplitude
m=[ Am*math.sin(2*math.pi*Fm*value) for value in t]
plt.plot(m)
plt.show()
```